# SSRS Report Code: Localization converts output to es-MX but the report Language is in en-US so it comes out wrong

Tags: reporting-services, localization

I have an SSRS report that uses the following code to calculate some statistics based on parameters selected by the user.

When this runs in Chrome on a machine with en-US localization, the output comes out correct.

When in Chrome in a machine with es-MX localization, the output is off because the decimal becomes a thousands separator (comma) and the thousands separator (comma) becomes a decimal.

Oddly enough, when I run in Edge on the same machine with es-MX, the output is correct.

How do I handle the localization of number formatting within the code embedded in the SSRS report?

Function `GetDataSetLabelFromValue`

```vb
    Public function GetDataSetLabelFromValue() as decimal
        dim i as integer
        dim rBar as decimal
        dim processSigma as decimal
        dim d2 as decimal 
        dim restartLow as integer
        restartLow = 0
        d2 = 1.128
        i = 0
        rBar = 0.0

        IF Report.Parameters!UseRestart.Value =FALSE THEN
           restartLow = 0
        ELSE 
          For i =0 to (Report.Parameters!RestartFilter.COUNT() - 1)
              IF CBool(Report.Parameters!RestartFilter.Label(i)) = 0 THEN
                  restartLow = i + 1
              END IF
          Next i
        END IF  

        IF Report.Parameters!LastBatch.Value = TRUE THEN
            for i = restartLow to (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count() - 2)
                rBar = rBar + ABS(Report.Parameters!PSigma.Label(i) - Report.Parameters!PSigma.Label(i+1))
            next i
        ELSE
            for i = restartLow  to (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count() - 3)
                rBar = rBar + ABS(Report.Parameters!PSigma.Label(i) - Report.Parameters!PSigma.Label(i+1))
            next i
        END IF

        IF (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count() - (restartLow))=0 OR (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count() - (restartLow) - 1)=0 THEN
            rBar = 0
        ELSE 
            IF Report.Parameters!LastBatch.Value = TRUE THEN  
                rBar = rBar / (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count() - (restartLow))
            ELSE
                rBar = rBar / (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count()-restartLow-1)
            END IF
        END IF

        processSigma = rBar / d2
        GetDataSetLabelFromValue = processSigma
    End Function
```

Function `GetAverageValue`

```vb
    Public function GetAverageValue() as decimal
        dim i as integer
        dim average as decimal  
        dim restartLow as integer
        restartLow = 0
        i = 0
        average = 0.0

        IF Report.Parameters!UseRestart.VALUE =FALSE THEN
            restartLow = 0
        ELSE 
            For i =0 to (Report.Parameters!RestartFilter.COUNT() - 1)
                IF CBool(Report.Parameters!RestartFilter.Label(i)) = 0 THEN
                    restartLow = i + 1
                END IF
                Next i
        END IF  

        IF Report.Parameters!LastBatch.Value = TRUE THEN
            for i = restartLow to (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count() - 1)
                average = average + (CDEC(Report.Parameters!PSigma.Label(i)))
            next i
        ELSE
            for i = restartLow to (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count() - 2)
                average = average + (CDEC(Report.Parameters!PSigma.Label(i)))
            next i
        END IF

        IF (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count() - (restartLow))=0 OR (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count() - (restartLow) - 1)=0 THEN
            average = 0
        ELSE
            IF Report.Parameters!LastBatch.Value = TRUE THEN  
                average = average / (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count() - (restartLow))
            ELSE
                average = average / (Report.Parameters!PSigma.Count()-restartLow-1)
            END IF
        END IF
        GetAverageValue = average
    End Function
```